# creating dataframe from string of names and other information

Tags: r

Trying to clean up some data and having trouble with the code for this case.  The strings look like this:

`string <- 'Inactive: UTA Jarrell Brantley, Juwan Morgan   DET Killian Hayes, Derrick Rose   '`

I want to make them into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
output <- data.frame('player' = c('Jarrell Brantley','Juwan Morgan','Killian Hayes','Derrick Rose'),
'team' = c('UTA','UTA','DET','DET'), 'status' = c('INACTIVE','INACTIVE','INACTIVE','INACTIVE'))
```

This is running through a for loop with many different strings, but the pattern of the string is always like this: "INACTIVE: team1 player_name1, player_name2, player_name3, team2 player_name4, player_name5  " (always space after final player_name)

I already have each team1 and team2 defined as objects team_away and team_home respectively, so those can be used as the 'UTA' and 'DET' strings in this case. Note that the number of players after team1 or team2 are not constant; sometimes there are 2 each, sometimes 4 different players after team1 with no mention of team2, etc.

Have tried different sub calls but I'm struggling with the proper syntax.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest a tidyverse pipe.

I'd think the `status` field is self-evident, so I'll skip that part for now. The rest:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gsub("^.*inactive:", "", string, ignore.case = TRUE) %>%
  trimws(.) %>%
  strsplit(., "\\s{2,}") %>%
  lapply(., strcapture, pattern = "^\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(.*)$", proto = list(team="", player="")) %>%
  bind_rows(.) %>%
  mutate(player = strsplit(player, ",\\s*")) %>%
  unnest(player)
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   team  player          
#   <chr> <chr>           
# 1 UTA   Jarrell Brantley
# 2 UTA   Juwan Morgan    
# 3 DET   Killian Hayes   
# 4 DET   Derrick Rose
```